# Docker pipe std output to shared volume

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and bash so please be patient with me :)

##### What I want do do?

- I have a node.js program which should always listen to some events. (run 24/7)
- If one of these events occur, it `console.log()`s something to `stdout` or `stderr`
- I want to write all of these outputs into a file.
- These logs should be persistent (That's why I want to write them to a shared volume)

##### My `Docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mintEvent:
    image: throvn/mint-event
    container_name: mintEventContainer
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs
    restart: "on-failure"
```

##### My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16
ENV NODE_ENV="PRODUCTION"
ENV CURRENTDATE="`date +'%Y-%m-%d %T'`"
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "tsconfig*.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
RUN 
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD [ "node", "build/index.js", "&>", "/logs/events.log" ]
```

##### What actually happens?

After running `docker build -t throvn/mint-event` and then `docker-compose up` in the directory, the program finishes with exit code 0. However, the program does not execute and terminates immediately. The log-file gets created but is completely empty.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Could you run a dedicated log collector like Fluentd?  Then you could [configure Docker to use a logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) without trying to manage log storage from inside the container.

Comment: Yeah thanks, thats an option. I think I have to go with this approach. I'm curious though why it won't work because it works perfectly fine on my local machine.

Comment: That [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) `CMD` line runs your script with two arguments, `&>` and the log path (you should be able to see them in `process.argv` or with libraries like `yargs`).  Do these cause a startup-time error; do you need [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) `CMD` without the JSON-array syntax?

Comment: Thats it!!! I needed shell form. They didn't cause a startup-time error, but shell form solved it. Thanks again!